# Detecting threshold area(s)

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv

I have thresholding image :

[image]

I want to know, can i detect "white zones" and draw rectangle around them (save data also wanted)
Or can i draw parallelepiped (polygon) and "say" area inside it is white?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to detect the white zones, just get the contours of the image. This can be done with:

```
vector<vector<Point>>contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(blackWhiteImage,
    contours,
    hierarchy,
    CV_RETR_TREE,
    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
    Point(0,0));
```

Then, you can generate the approximate bounding box that models every contour you extracted with:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ){
   approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]),
       contours_poly[i],
       3,
       true );
       //3 is epsilon tuning param for bias-variance trade off
       //true denotes contours are closed

   boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
}
```

Once this is done, you can access the boundingRect objects in your boundingRect array just like you would access any other array.

Simular code for EmguCV (C#) without approximation:

```
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat hierarchy;

CvInvoke.FindContours(binMat, contours, hierarchy, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; ++i)
{
    if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]) > 8)
    {
        Rectangle rc = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contours[i]);
        CvInvoke.Rectangle(srcMat, rc, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is contours_poly? Same for Mat(...)

Comment: Mat(...) is constructing an instance of cv::Mat so that we  can pass the correctly typed param to the boundingRect constructor.

Also, my bad for not including the initialization of contours_poly originally. It is just a variable holding the approximate polygons that you get from approxPolyDP so that we can use them to construct matrices to pass to the boundingRect constructor

Comment: Alright. I Made some code in c# using your examples. I think i will take your answer.